# Cisco ASA 5510 w/ AIP SSM - Can it inspect SSL traffic?

Tags: ssl, cisco, certificate, cisco-asa, ips

Is is possible for a AIP module within a Cisco 5510 ASA to decrypt and inspect SSL traffic?

I have asked my local vendor (who placed the devices of which I speak) and they say that the AIP module is incapable of reviewing encrypted content.  I work with web application firewalls fairly commonly thus familiar with the ability to install a web certificate on a appliance to allow it to see into the SSL traffic.  Is that impossible on an ASA w/ a IPS module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. The ASA does not perform SSL termination (beyond that required for WebVPN and AnyConnect VPN), so it is unable to provide a decrypted data stream for the AIP to inspect. You would need to position something else in front of the ASA that can perform SSL termination, such as a Web application firewall, as you mentioned. Some load-balancing products (e.g. Cisco CSM-SSL) can do this as well.